# .NET - Is the MSB of int32 platform agnostic?

Tags: .net, integer, platform-agnostic

I have the following code for getting the MSB (Most Significant Bit) from a non-negative integer, `Int32` to be more specific:

```
private static readonly int[] powersOf2 = new int[]
                                        {
                                            1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384,
                                            32768, 65536, 131072, 262144, 524288, 1048576, 2097152, 4194304,
                                            8388608, 16777216, 33554432, 67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912,
                                            1073741824
                                        };

public static int GetMsb(int value)
{
    for (int k = powersOf2.Length - 1; k >= 0; k--)
    {
        var bit = (value & powersOf2[k]) != 0;
        if (bit)
            return (k + 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Again: given that value is not negative.

My question is:
Does the .NET framework guarantee that this code would run appropriately on every platform: x86/Windows/Linux/Sun/64bit?

Is the `Int32` representation inside .NET, including **Endianness** and bit/byte order, platform agnostic?

Thanks in advance!
BTW, if this is kind of a duplicate - please comment about it ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing platform specific about the base-2 number system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you treat it **as an `int`**, yes it is platform agnostic. This includes all arithmetic and bitwise (`<<` , `>>` etc) operations. The opcodes always make sure that it does what you expect.

However! If you peek below the covers, it *might* matter; for example `BitConverter.GetBytes(int)` and `BitConverter.ToInt32` care about the endianness. You can check this with `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`; it is usually `true` on "regular" .NET, but could be `false` perhaps on IA64, or XNA or Mono on some architectures.

The same logic applies to any unsafe code that coerces (for example) between `byte*` and `int*`, or any *unions* constructed via `[StructLayout]`.

But in *regular* code, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The endianness is platform dependent, but your code here doesn't depend on endianness at all.

Endianness only comes into play when you use low level stuff like pointers, unions(StructLayout:Explicit) or BitConverter.

Bitshifts, integer arithmetic and normal casts between integer types are endian agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will always work.

That's not because the representation of Int32 won't change from platform to platform, but because your code is well-written enough not to rely on it: you are ANDing Int32s with other Int32s. In the event that the format did change, the change would affect both the number you're testing, and the entries in your powers-of-2 table, equally - so the code would still work.

Answer (score 0):

The code is portable, however, it returns 0 as the MSB for `int.MinValue` wich is in fact 0x80000000 in hexa, because you're working with signed integers. Here is a code that works for all bits, I believe, and does not need any precalculated values:

```
public static int GetMsb(int value)
{
    for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((value & 0x80000000) != 0) return i;
        value <<= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or with a `uint`:

```
public static int GetMsb(uint value)
{
    for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if ((value & 0x80000000) != 0) return i;
        value <<= 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "given that value is not negative". thanks for the suggested code, though.